# jquery moving elements in clockwise

Tags: jquery, html

Im very very new to jquery
I write an page that have a container with a square on the center and 4 Rectangles around it - every one with another color.
What I want to do is to move them with animation in clockwise
I only need some guidance.. since I don't know how I can rotate elements in jquery or know how to change the right place ...

any Ideas?(I dont know if I really need rotation)

Comment: How about some portion of the code you already have?

Comment: I only have the basic code for the square and the structure..have no clue where to start the jquery...

Comment: @Nusha - even that helps.  Also, do you mean rotate as in switch each of their positions in a clockwise animation, or spin the squares in their current positions?

Comment: your explanation wasn't really clear, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U3u5x/2/) the type of animation you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to rotate all elements, check this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/VBN5W/3/

Take note, that the background colors are used to allow a better visual representation of watts going on!

**EDITED:**

Now a version where only the numerated elements rotate:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/VBN5W/4/

Answer (score 0):

Put your four rectangles in a div, with each inner rectangle bound to the edges then rotate the container with [jQuery-Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/).

Comment: but rotating the container will have the wanted animation? is that possible?